# Error on cordova build app

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, web

I'm using cordova CLI - v: 6.2.3 for build my app. But, in the build time the console show-me the error, below:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: symbol lookup error: 
/usr/lib/jni/libnative-platform-curses.so: undefined symbol: tgetent
Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 127
```

I tried to solve the problem by changing the `gradle` file in gradle folder

Please, someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. I download the file in `https://packages.debian.org/sid/libnative-platform-jni` and execute.